# What is generative testing in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript, clojure.spec, generative-testing

I came across `Generative Testing in Clojure with spec` notion and would like to learn about it.

Also providing some examples would be very useful.

Comment: Also found this: http://dev.solita.fi/2017/04/10/making-software-testing-easier-with-clojure.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As introductory reading we've got the [Rationale and Overview](https://clojure.org/about/spec) along with the [Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) which should provide you with information both about the why and the how.

If you'd like a somewhat complex example, we can take the `string->semantic-version` function of `leiningen.release`:

```
(defn string->semantic-version [version-string]
  "Create map representing the given version string. Returns nil if the
  string does not follow guidelines setforth by Semantic Versioning 2.0.0,
  http://semver.org/"
  ;; <MajorVersion>.<MinorVersion>.<PatchVersion>[-<Qualifier>][-SNAPSHOT]
  (if-let [[_ major minor patch qualifier snapshot]
           (re-matches
            #"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:-(?!SNAPSHOT)([^\-]+))?(?:-(SNAPSHOT))?"
            version-string)]
    (->> [major minor patch]
         (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
         (zipmap [:major :minor :patch])
         (merge {:qualifier qualifier
                 :snapshot snapshot}))))
```

It takes a string and tries to parse it into a program-readable map representing the version number of some artifact. A spec for it could look like:

First some dependencies

```
(ns leiningen.core.spec.util
  (:require
   [clojure.spec           :as spec]
   [clojure.spec.gen       :as gen]
   [miner.strgen           :as strgen]
   [clojure.spec.test      :as test]
   [leiningen.release      :as release]))
```

then a helper macro

```
(defmacro stregex
  "Defines a spec which matches a string based on a given string
  regular expression. This the classical type of regex as in the
  clojure regex literal #\"\""
  [string-regex]
  `(spec/with-gen
     (spec/and string? #(re-matches ~string-regex %))
     #(strgen/string-generator ~string-regex)))
```

followed by a definition of a semantic version

```
(spec/def ::semantic-version-string
  (stregex #"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(-\w+)?(-SNAPSHOT)?"))
```

and some helper-specs

```
(spec/def ::non-blank-string
  (spec/and string? #(not (str/blank? %))))
(spec/def ::natural-number
  (spec/int-in 0 Integer/MAX_VALUE))
```

for the definition of the keys in the resulting map

```
(spec/def ::release/major     ::natural-number)
(spec/def ::release/minor     ::natural-number)
(spec/def ::release/patch     ::natural-number)
(spec/def ::release/qualifier ::non-blank-string)
(spec/def ::release/snapshot  #{"SNAPSHOT"})
```

and the map itself

```
(spec/def ::release/semantic-version-map
  (spec/keys :req-un [::release/major ::release/minor ::release/patch
                      ::release/qualifier ::release/snapshot]))
```

followed by the function spec:

```
(spec/fdef release/string->semantic-version
           :args (spec/cat :version-str ::release/semantic-version-string)
           :ret  ::release/semantic-version-map)
```

By now we can let Clojure Spec generate test data and feed it into the function itself in order to test whether it meets the constraints we've put up for it:

```
(test/check `release/version-map->string)
=> ({:spec #object[clojure.spec$fspec_impl$reify__14248 0x16c2555 "clojure.spec$fspec_impl$reify__14248@16c2555"],
     :clojure.spec.test.check/ret {:result true,
                                   :num-tests 1000,
                                   :seed 1491922864713},
     :sym leiningen.release/version-map->string})
```

This tells us that out of the 1000 test cases spec generated for us the function passed every single one.

Comment: Great answer. Would you be able to talk more about the need for the helper macro compared to achieving the same thing just using a function?

Comment: The helper macro only exists because I repeat that code multiple times throughout my real world code. There's actually no point to it in the above example except perhaps for readability.

Answer (score 8):

You may find it easiest to get started looking at `clojure/test.check` before you dive into `Clojure Spec`.  [From the project page:](https://github.com/clojure/test.check)

```
(require '[clojure.test.check :as tc])
(require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])
(require '[clojure.test.check.properties :as prop])

(def sort-idempotent-prop
  (prop/for-all [v (gen/vector gen/int)]
    (= (sort v) (sort (sort v)))))

(tc/quick-check 100 sort-idempotent-prop)
;; => {:result true, :num-tests 100, :seed 1382488326530}
```

> In prose, this test reads: for all vectors of integers, v, sorting v is equal to sorting v twice.
>
> What happens if our test fails? test.check will try and find 'smaller' inputs that still fail. This process is called shrinking.
>   Let's see it in action:

```
(def prop-sorted-first-less-than-last
  (prop/for-all [v (gen/not-empty (gen/vector gen/int))]
    (let [s (sort v)]
      (< (first s) (last s)))))

(tc/quick-check 100 prop-sorted-first-less-than-last)
;; => {:result false, :failing-size 0, :num-tests 1, :fail [[3]],
       :shrunk {:total-nodes-visited 5, :depth 2, :result false,
                :smallest [[0]]}}
```

Comment: Nice Clojure/West 2017 presentation by Eric Normand on test.check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5i_OiZw6Sw